# When click change to text-area, When outside click change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make a function like PHPadmin what they are using on when showing the table, when click the div filed, change to text-area, and when click outside of the div, change it back to the div filed. The code below is wrong, I cannot change back to the div filed when I click outside. Please help me to improve the code.

JS:

```
$('#editor #gird_edit').bind({
  click: function() {
            $(this).html('<textarea id="gird_edit">'+$(this).text()+'</textarea>');
  },
  blur: function() {
            $(this).html('<div id="gird_edit">'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<div id='editor'>
<div id='gird_edit'>hallo world</div>
<div id='gird_edit'>hallo world 2</div>
<div id='gird_edit'>hallo world 3</div>
</div>
```

I only have 8 reputations, I cannot vote you back. However, I sincerely appreciate your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huhEG/)

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huhEG/3/)

when `$(this).html(textarea)` is done, `div` is already blur. so the onBlur didn't work

```
$('#editor #gird_edit').bind({
    click: function() {
        var tex = $(this).text();
        var textarea = $('<textarea id="gird_edit">'+tex+'</textarea>');
        $(this).html(textarea);
        textarea.focus();
        textarea.blur(function(){
            var currentText = textarea.val();
            if(currentText == tex)//not change
                textarea.parent().text(tex);
            else //changed
                alert(currentText);
        });
    }
});
```

---

**edit 3:**

```
else{
    textarea.parent().text(currentText);
    //something else
}
```

find more [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: When after change the value inside of the text-area, click out-side. The filed will change back into the original value. How should I re-read the value??

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfect! Just one miner question, the editor cursor will automatically go back to beginning no matter where you click, is this possible be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

check [this](http://jsbin.com/amezul/1/edit) jsbin i just made, if you need anything else i'm glad to help.

Comment: Sure, no problem, we're here to help, happy holidays!

Comment: ups, yeah sorry about that, just throw this line if( pressed.is("textarea") ) return; right after var pressed = $(e.target);  [link](http://jsbin.com/amezul/6/edit) has the updated version

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this be possible to determine the event only by one id? like I have same div id='gird_edit'

Comment: It's possible to have multiple tags ith the same id, but it's considered a bad practice, it should be addressed multiple elements with the same CLASS, so the id is unique to each element. The answer given form @Teifi is first class indeed and it's using a single id for multiple tags. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers!! I am a beginner, but I wonder if this is true. Js is better to use class to indentify instead of id?

Comment: No, id searching is the fastest way to get elements, but and id SHOULD be unique, if you need to target several elements you should add them to the same class, that way, your html WILL be valid. But as i said before, your code should work ok ( in this case ) there are scenarios where you won't be able to duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

When you first click on the `#gird_edit` it is a div, so `this` is a div, and you can replace its contents to change things.  However, when you blur away `#gird_edit` is a textarea, so if you change its contents you're not really changing what you want to change (your just changing the insides of your textarea).

What you want to change is the div that's around the textarea, ie. the "parent" of that textarea.  In other words, try:

```
blur: function() {
        $(this).parent().html('<div id="gird_edit">'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
}
```

Comment: the problem is like, the blur function will no response to the text-area which generated by click function.